# Nodemon issue, stays hanging

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I use currently the following:

```
windows 10
NodeJS: v10.9.0
npm : 6.2.0
nodemon: 1.18.3
```

And have the following issue, when I press control s after changing something in my files nodemon will hang. It will not update the server and when I press control s multiple times it shows the following:

[image]

What could possibly causing this and how can I potentially fix this?

I tried reinstalling different versions of nodmeon, and reinstalling nodeJS (different versions).

Comment: Could you please post the reasons you believe nodemon is not updating the server and why it is hanging?  IMO those would be key to troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: I literally have no idea, it was working on windows 7, got windows 10 now and installed it using 

npm i nodemon -g

Now it doesn't work, lots of stuff

Comment: So do none of your web requests generate responses?  Have you tried writing a line to the console at the end of app.js/server.js so that you know the server has started?

Comment: Yes you can even see in the picture, the log:

API running on localhost3000

Comment: When I used nodemon when running an API, I sometimes had "port is already in use" issues because it restarted too quick and the port didn't have time to be freed from the machine. Try to think if that's might be the type of your problem, i.e. one of your modules restarts made this issue. Try to log app.js for each couple of lines and see where it stuck. Also, your app.js would help us understand where is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use the legacy flag `nodemon -L` when running it.

Comment: As this isn't a definitive solution it would be better to add this as a comment to the Question rather than an Answer.